# How to create a favourites relationship in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relationships, favorites

I am trying to create a "favourite" button for my rails site. I have two models, users and materials. I have done the following:

a) I created a new table "favmats" which looks like this in the schema:

```
create_table "favmats", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "material_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
end
```

b) I set up relationships between the models:

```
class Favmat
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :material
end

class Materials
  has_many :favmats
  has_many :users, :through => :favmats
end

class Users
  has_many :favmats
  has_many :materials, :through => :favmats
end
```

c) I created a form on the materials show page that should execute code to create the new relationship in the database. There seems to be a problem with this. The code is thus:

```
<%= form_for @favmat do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :material_id, value: @material.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Favourite" %>
<% end %>
```

d) I created a method in the favmats_controller that looks like this:

```
def create
  @material = Material.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @favmat.save
      format.html { redirect_to @material }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render 'new' }
      format.js
    end
  end   
end
```

Needless to say, this is not working. Any ideas what I should do? My biggest sources of confusion are where I should create a new favmats object and how.

Comment: What part of it is not working? Error message? Routing issue?

Comment: You can use [socialization](https://github.com/Shreshtt/socialization) gem. It give lots of functionality. You can use its Like function as a favorite.

Comment: hmmm actually you are using find method and saving the record. You need to use .new method to initiize the record, pass the params record in it and then record save record using .save method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your create function is trying to use an `:id` param that, in a create action, shouldn't exist.
It also doesn't build a favmat object, it just tries to save something that doesn't exist.

```
def create
  @favmat = Favmat.new(params[:favmat])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @favmat.save
      format.html { redirect_to @favmat.material }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render 'new' }
      format.js
    end
  end   
end
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's great. Quick supplementary question: why do I not need to code @favmat.save before the conditional statement?